# Jenkins pipeline job - Workspace directory is not created

Tags: jenkins

I have created a pipeline job and when i triggered the job, workspace directory is not created, due to this the job gets failed.

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on acs in /usr/share/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline1
```

Pipeline1 is the workspace name, but its not getting created in Linux machine.
I tried restarting, but not able to re-solve this issue. 
any advise please

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there.

Comment: may be the user doesn't have the permission to create a directory.